# Table becomes selected when using contentEditable

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make td-elements editable with contentEditable.
This seems to work but for some reason the both the table and the 'cell' get selected.

I don't know how to prevent this behavior.
This is what I got so far.

```js
 document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'td') {
   this.contentEditable = true;
   this.focus();
  }
 });
 
 document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'td') {
   this.removeAttribute("contentEditable");
  }
 });
```

```css
td[contentEditable] {
    background:black;
    color:white;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" id="tableCompleted">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jesse</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>David</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>No</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three minor changes to your code:

1. CSS `td[contentEditable]`  applies to a `td` even if `contentEditable` is set to false. So it should be `td[contentEditable=true]` to ensure that the styles are not applied when `contentEditable` attribute is set to false.
2. In the `click` handler, instead of doing `this.contentEditable`, I am using `event.target`.
3. Instead of listening to blur event on the body, I am subscribing the active `td` element to observe the blur event.

   *Note: I haven't added the code for `removeEventListener` after the blur event is handled, but you should do that.

```js
function handleBlur(event) {
  event.target.contentEditable = false;
}

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'td') {
    event.target.contentEditable = true;
    event.target.focus();

    event.target.addEventListener("blur", handleBlur);
  }
});
```

```css
td[contentEditable=true] {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

td {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<table class="table" id="tableCompleted">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>A</th>
      <th>B</th>
      <th>C</th>
      <th>D</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
      <td>No</td>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jesse</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>David</td>
      <td>No</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
      <td>No</td>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```